# Clear datetime-local with required

Tags: html, frontend, datetimepicker, datetime-local

I have a problem with datetime-local picker in HTML5. I want to clear the datetime with the clear button, but this is not possible because the "required" function inside the input will not allow. I will let a piece of code to see the differences. One is with required and one without required. Do you know how to keep the "required" and also clear the input from ex: "15/03/2022 00:00 AM" to mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --.
Thank you.

```css
label {
    display: block;
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input,
label {
    margin: .4rem 0;
}
```

```html
    <input type="datetime-local" name="start_timestamp" id="start_timestamp" required>


<label for="meeting-time">Choose a time for your appointment:</label>

<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time"
   name="meeting-time">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible.

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/datetime-local) :

> The control's UI varies in general from browser to browser.

On Chrome the **clear button** is inside a popover and does nothing if the field is `required`. But on Firefox (following screenshot) the **clear button** is inside the `input` and is not shown if the field is `required`.

[image]

You should add your own **clear button** next to each `input` :

```js
function clearInput(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).value = "";
}
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input,
label {
    margin: .4rem 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="start_timestamp" id="start_timestamp" required>
<button type="button" title="clear" onclick="clearInput('start_timestamp')">x</button>

<label for="meeting-time">Choose a time for your appointment:</label>

<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time"
   name="meeting-time">
<button type="button" title="clear" onclick="clearInput('meeting-time')">x</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The attribute required is responsible for whether the reset button is shown or not. If required is set, you must solve the reset programmatically. You do this for the type `datetime-local` with `yourDateElement.valueAsDate = null`.

```js
const clearBtn = document.getElementById('clear-btn');
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const d =   document.getElementById('start_timestamp');
  d.valueAsDate = null
})
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input,
label {
    margin: .4rem 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="start_timestamp" id="start_timestamp" value="" required>

<button id="clear-btn" onclick="clear()">clear</button>


<label for="meeting-time">Choose a time for your appointment:</label>

<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time"
   name="meeting-time">
```

#### Works for Chrome too

```js
const clearBtn = document.getElementById('clear-btn');
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const d =   document.querySelector('input[type=datetime-local]');
  d.value = 0
})
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input,
label {
    margin: .4rem 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="start_timestamp" id="start_timestamp" value="" required>

<button id="clear-btn" onclick="clear()">clear</button>


<label for="meeting-time">Choose a time for your appointment:</label>

<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time"
   name="meeting-time">
```

Comment: This works on Firefox but an error is thrown on Edge and on Chrome.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for this information! I wasn't aware of that. I add a update to my answer

Comment: @Tom `Only d.value = 0 would work`